# Conversion tracking in Email (Marketing Cloud) not working - Please help

Tags: marketing-cloud, conversion, tracking-extract

When creating a button with a link in Marketing Cloud content builder there is the option to add a link URL, Title and Tracking Alias and a 'conversion tracking link' tick box. We have set up our buttons to contain all of these things inc. the conversion tracking box being ticked - however, when looking into the tracking of this email no conversion data is shown (despite the link in question being clicked).

I investigated further and when looking at the HTML of the button the conversion section says - 'conversion=false' - which I assume means it isn't being tracked. So I tried to manually change the HTML to 'conversion=true' - however, this change does not save.

My question is - How can we get conversions to be tracked on this button?

Comment: Hi. I met another issue. I added the button(conversion=true) and saved. But I can not capture the parameters in the conversion link in the email. Did you resolve this issue? Would you mind to share it with me? Thanks!